# How do I update a multiple row with checkbox

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, ejb

I want to update a particular column in my database with the word 'trash' but I need to first tick the values in check box. Then when u tick the checkbox, the system will only update the status field of the id's selected

```
    public void updateNow(Messages message){
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("Update Messages set status = 'trash' WHERE id =:id");
 query.setParameter("id", message.getId());
        query.executeUpdate();
}

}


<%
                
//updating the filed

String[] arr = request.getParameterValues("content");


        int sum=0;
        if(request.getParameter("update")!=null){
                        
        try{    
       
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
       
      sl.updateNow(arr[i]);
            sum++;
        msg = "<script>alert('You have move message to trash')</script>";
        }
        }catch (Exception e){
                      
           msg="Please Do select an email before performing an action" + e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
             
                }

                %>
                
                
                <html>
                <body>
                <form action="" method="post">
    <% 
    
    List inboxFetch = sl.allMessages(user, "inbox");
    Iterator inboxIterate = inboxFetch.iterator();
            
  while(inboxIterate.hasNext()){
   Messages all = (Messages) inboxIterate.next();
   
    %>
    
    <input type="checkbox" value="<%=all.getId() %>" name="content">
        
    
    <%
        }

    %>
    <br />
    <hr />
     <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Update</button>
         </form>
        
        </body>
        </html>
```

Please how do I achieve this? I have been on this code now for quite some hours seems I can't get through it

Comment: does your checkboxes have value of `id` if  or not and when you submit your form what does `arr` have in it .try to print and check onces

Comment: The code is throwing this exception - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading . I dont know how to solve this issue

Comment: what does `<%=all.getId() %>` have in it ? are values display or not  in your checkboxes ?

Comment: Thanks man.. u have opened my eyes to finally solve the problem...... ur comment doesnt have a like button though. Lol